# How to find File Name using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to find out if a filename exists in my Image folder, how can I do this in a function using javascript?

How about call a function from Javascript to a C# File? (ON SERVER)

Thank you

Comment: Short Answer: You can't.

Comment: How about call a function from Javascript to a C# File?

Comment: Is the 'Image' folder on the client or server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript from the browser does not have access to your Image folder on your local computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a server side language. Javascript won't have access to your folders on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide more context

if your javascript is running within browser and you want to check if file exists on client's computer - you can't

if you want to check Image folder on server - you could do AJAX request for that image and then check if HTTP response code is 200 although that would also blow up your traffic and is not a great choice

best option would be to do AJAX request that will invoke a check on server side like /check?image_name=file.jpg

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is `executed by Browser as Client-side scripting` so it `doesn't have access to local file system` to check whether file exists or not to check file exists or not you need to use `Server Side Scripting`.